# Unable to launch EC2 with IAM role as a member of Administrators group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, user-permissions

On AWS member of Administrators group is unable to launch EC2 instances with IAM role. The same user can create IAM roles and even manage users in IAM console.

User seems to have all possible permissions. What could be missing?

Comment: What command are they using and what error are they getting?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#permission-to-pass-iam-roles) states you need `ec2:RunInstances`, `ec2:AssociateIamInstanceProfile`, `ec2:ReplaceIamInstanceProfileAssociation` and `iam:PassRole`. Do they have all of those?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
         "ec2:RunInstances",
         "ec2:AssociateIamInstanceProfile",
         "ec2:ReplaceIamInstanceProfileAssociation"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:PassRole",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: User has administrator access. {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Do you have any `"Deny"` policies?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently rights were OK. The mistake was made when creating the role. For instance roles EC2 had to be selected on the first step (not the desired access). Permissions were available on the next step.